# Change wordpress login panel logo with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Changing the background works perfectly as does changing the logo when you hover the mouse over it, but changing the logo for an hour does not work. I suspect that the problem lies in the bad execution of lines of the java script.

functions.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function () {
wp_enqueue_style( 'amereo-login-styles', get_theme_file_uri('login-styles.css'), [], false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'amereo-login-scripts', get_theme_file_uri('login-scripts.js'), [], false, true);
} );
```

login-scripts.js

```
            console.log('works');
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = 1;
    //var hours = date.getHours();

    if (hours <= 1){
        document.body.classList.add("a");
        document.a.classList.add("night");
    }
    else if(hours <= 2){
        document.body.classList.add("b");
        document.a.classList.add("night");
    }        
    else if(hours <= 3){
        document.body.classList.add("c");
        document.a.classList.add("night");
    }       
    else if(hours <= 4){
        document.body.classList.add("d");
        document.a.classList.add("night");
    }       
    else if(hours <= 5){
        document.body.classList.add("e");
        document.a.classList.add("night");
    }       
    else if(hours <= 6){
        document.body.classList.add("f");
        document.a.classList.add("day");
    }       
    else if(hours <= 7){
        document.body.classList.add("g");
        document.a.classList.add("day");
    }
```

login-styles.css

```
    #login a {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    #login a.day {
    background-image: url("images/login_logo_day.png");
    }
    
    #login a.night {
    background-image: url("images/login_logo_night.png");
    }
    
    
    #login a:hover {
    background-image: url("images/login_logo_hover.png");
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: `hours` is always `1`. So you'll always only reach the first `if` statement.

Comment: Sory, I knew it, I forgot to change it and I specially set it to 1 to see if the first if works and it doesn't. I get the default wordpress logo and not my custom one

Comment: I have set there: var hours = date.getHours();

Comment: There is no problem with this, only that the script does not use .night and .day

Comment: Be sure to check your console in the future. `document.a` is not a property that exists and should therefor throw an error. What you were looking for, based on the answer you provided yourself, is `document.querySelector('#login a')` which will look for the element without having to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to functions.php:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`
And I replaced the java script code:

```
        console.log('works');
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var login = jQuery('#login a');

    if (hours <= 1){
        document.body.classList.add("a");
        login.addClass('night');
    }
    else if(hours <= 2){
        document.body.classList.add("b");
        login.addClass('night');
    }        
    else if(hours <= 3){
        document.body.classList.add("c");
        login.addClass('night');
    }       
    else if(hours <= 4){
        document.body.classList.add("d");
        login.addClass('night');
    }       
    else if(hours <= 5){
        document.body.classList.add("e");
        login.addClass('night');
    }       
    else if(hours <= 6){
        document.body.classList.add("f");
        login.addClass('night');
    }       
    else if(hours <= 7){
        document.body.classList.add("g");
        login.addClass('day');
    }
```